# Problems with display inline-block in IE7

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, internet-explorer-7

I am using .ui-helper-clearfix { display: inline-block; } in jquery_custom_datatable.css and jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css while fixing the browser compatibilty issues.I came over with a issue where i need to remove `.ui-helper-clearfix { display: inline-block; }` which is effecting an extra width on my table only in IE7.Removing it havent effected the css on IE8 and mozilla.But made some adverse affects on other tables in IE7 such as removing the width where it is needed.I want to know is there any alternative for this one so that instead of removing it will there be any other alterative fix for `.ui-helper-clearfix { display: inline-block; }` for IE7.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before `inline-block`, we used `floats`. This may work in your situation, but you'll probably have to tweak your CSS a bit.

Comment: Thanks,thats working the same as in.I dont need to remove the inline-block.But regarding the other width issues i think i need to tweak a bit of my css.any ways thank you Diodeus